# sqlalchemy escape underscore in column name (PYTHON)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL query that runs just fine in Workbench but I can't get to work in Python using sqlalchemy. The statement ran fine until I added `AND _deleted_at IS NULL`. I have figured out that the column name is the problem and assume that the underscores are the issue. The "GroupId" column and the "_deleted_at" column are in the same table "contact_group_assign".

The full query string that works is

```
 sql ='SELECT *, CASE WHEN Purchaser20 <> "0" THEN SUBSTR(Purchaser20,1,POSITION(";" IN Purchaser20)-1)\
ELSE 0 END AS PurchaserId \
FROM (SELECT sales.ItemName, sales.Qty, sales.ProductId, contact.Id AS ContactId, concat(contact.FirstName, " ", contact.LastName) as NAME, \
            CASE WHEN contact._data LIKE "%%PurchaserID%%" THEN SUBSTR(contact._data,POSITION("PurchaserID" IN contact._data)+15,20)\
            ELSE 0 END as Purchaser20 \
            FROM contact_group_assign registry\
            LEFT JOIN (select order_item.ItemName, order_item.Qty,  order_item.ProductId, invoice.ContactId \
            FROM order_item\
            LEFT JOIN invoice_item ON order_item.Id=invoice_item.OrderItemId\
            LEFT JOIN invoice ON invoice_item.InvoiceId = invoice.Id\
            LEFT JOIN payment ON invoice_item.InvoiceId = payment.InvoiceId\
            LEFT JOIN invoice_payment ON invoice_item.InvoiceId = invoice_payment.InvoiceId\
            WHERE ProductId IN (3682,3684,3686,3688,3690,3692,3694,3696,3698,3700,3702,3704,3706,3708)\
        ) sales\
        ON registry.ContactId = sales.ContactId\
        JOIN contact ON registry.ContactId=contact.Id\
        WHERE GroupId = 22492\
    ) a'
```

The line that breaks is the Where clause

```
WHERE GroupId = 22492 AND _deleted_at IS NULL\
```

The error I receive is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1808, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1807     if not evt_handled:
-> 1808         self.dialect.do_execute(
   1809             cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1810         )
   1812 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:732, in DefaultDialect.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    731 def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 732     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:148, in Cursor.execute(self, query, args)
    146 query = self.mogrify(query, args)
--> 148 result = self._query(query)
    149 self._executed = query

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:310, in Cursor._query(self, q)
    309 self._clear_result()
--> 310 conn.query(q)
    311 self._do_get_result()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:548, in Connection.query(self, sql, unbuffered)
    547 self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
--> 548 self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
    549 return self._affected_rows

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:775, in Connection._read_query_result(self, unbuffered)
    774     result = MySQLResult(self)
--> 775     result.read()
    776 self._result = result

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:1156, in MySQLResult.read(self)
   1155 try:
-> 1156     first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
   1158     if first_packet.is_ok_packet():

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:725, in Connection._read_packet(self, packet_type)
    724         self._result.unbuffered_active = False
--> 725     packet.raise_for_error()
    726 return packet

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py:221, in MysqlPacket.raise_for_error(self)
    220     print("errno =", errno)
--> 221 err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py:143, in raise_mysql_exception(data)
    142     errorclass = InternalError if errno < 1000 else OperationalError
--> 143 raise errorclass(errno, errval)

OperationalError: (1052, "Column '_deleted_at' in where clause is ambiguous")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Chris Hill\OneDrive - Brave Thinking Institute\dblv_05_22\final\create list with guest designation.ipynb Cell 2' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 registry = pd.read_sql(sql, cnx)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:592, in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    583     return pandas_sql.read_table(
    584         sql,
    585         index_col=index_col,
   (...)
    589         chunksize=chunksize,
    590     )
    591 else:
--> 592     return pandas_sql.read_query(
    593         sql,
    594         index_col=index_col,
    595         params=params,
    596         coerce_float=coerce_float,
    597         parse_dates=parse_dates,
    598         chunksize=chunksize,
    599     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1557, in SQLDatabase.read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params, chunksize, dtype)
   1509 """
   1510 Read SQL query into a DataFrame.
   1511 
   (...)
   1553 
   1554 """
   1555 args = _convert_params(sql, params)
-> 1557 result = self.execute(*args)
   1558 columns = result.keys()
   1560 if chunksize is not None:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:1402, in SQLDatabase.execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1400 def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1401     """Simple passthrough to SQLAlchemy connectable"""
-> 1402     return self.connectable.execution_options().execute(*args, **kwargs)

File <string>:2, in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py:401, in _decorate_with_warning.<locals>.warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    399 if not skip_warning:
    400     _warn_with_version(message, version, wtype, stacklevel=3)
--> 401 return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:3152, in Engine.execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   3134 """Executes the given construct and returns a
   3135 :class:`_engine.CursorResult`.
   3136 
   (...)
   3149 
   3150 """
   3151 connection = self.connect(close_with_result=True)
-> 3152 return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1280, in Connection.execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   1271 if isinstance(statement, util.string_types):
   1272     util.warn_deprecated_20(
   1273         "Passing a string to Connection.execute() is "
   1274         "deprecated and will be removed in version 2.0.  Use the "
   (...)
   1277         "driver-level SQL string."
   1278     )
-> 1280     return self._exec_driver_sql(
   1281         statement,
   1282         multiparams,
   1283         params,
   1284         _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS,
   1285         future=False,
   1286     )
   1288 try:
   1289     meth = statement._execute_on_connection

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1584, in Connection._exec_driver_sql(self, statement, multiparams, params, execution_options, future)
   1574         (
   1575             statement,
   1576             distilled_params,
   (...)
   1580             statement, distilled_parameters, execution_options
   1581         )
   1583 dialect = self.dialect
-> 1584 ret = self._execute_context(
   1585     dialect,
   1586     dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_statement,
   1587     statement,
   1588     distilled_parameters,
   1589     execution_options,
   1590     statement,
   1591     distilled_parameters,
   1592 )
   1594 if not future:
   1595     if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1851, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1848             branched.close()
   1850 except BaseException as e:
-> 1851     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
   1852         e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
   1853     )
   1855 return result

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:2032, in Connection._handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   2030     util.raise_(newraise, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e)
   2031 elif should_wrap:
-> 2032     util.raise_(
   2033         sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   2034     )
   2035 else:
   2036     util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py:207, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    204     exception.__cause__ = replace_context
    206 try:
--> 207     raise exception
    208 finally:
    209     # credit to
    210     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    211     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle
    212     del exception, replace_context, from_, with_traceback

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py:1808, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1806                 break
   1807     if not evt_handled:
-> 1808         self.dialect.do_execute(
   1809             cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1810         )
   1812 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:
   1813     self.dispatch.after_cursor_execute(
   1814         self,
   1815         cursor,
   (...)
   1819         context.executemany,
   1820     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py:732, in DefaultDialect.do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    731 def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 732     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:148, in Cursor.execute(self, query, args)
    144     pass
    146 query = self.mogrify(query, args)
--> 148 result = self._query(query)
    149 self._executed = query
    150 return result

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:310, in Cursor._query(self, q)
    308 self._last_executed = q
    309 self._clear_result()
--> 310 conn.query(q)
    311 self._do_get_result()
    312 return self.rowcount

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:548, in Connection.query(self, sql, unbuffered)
    546     sql = sql.encode(self.encoding, "surrogateescape")
    547 self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
--> 548 self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
    549 return self._affected_rows

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:775, in Connection._read_query_result(self, unbuffered)
    773 else:
    774     result = MySQLResult(self)
--> 775     result.read()
    776 self._result = result
    777 if result.server_status is not None:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:1156, in MySQLResult.read(self)
   1154 def read(self):
   1155     try:
-> 1156         first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
   1158         if first_packet.is_ok_packet():
   1159             self._read_ok_packet(first_packet)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py:725, in Connection._read_packet(self, packet_type)
    723     if self._result is not None and self._result.unbuffered_active is True:
    724         self._result.unbuffered_active = False
--> 725     packet.raise_for_error()
    726 return packet

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py:221, in MysqlPacket.raise_for_error(self)
    219 if DEBUG:
    220     print("errno =", errno)
--> 221 err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py:143, in raise_mysql_exception(data)
    141 if errorclass is None:
    142     errorclass = InternalError if errno < 1000 else OperationalError
--> 143 raise errorclass(errno, errval)

OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1052, "Column '_deleted_at' in where clause is ambiguous")
```

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided

Comment: "GroupID" and "_deleted_at" are both in the same table.

Comment: "does NOT work" is not a particularly helpful description of the problem. Do you get an error message? If so, please [edit] your question to include the stack trace.

Comment: Also please include a [mcve]. Executing `qry = text("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 1 AND _deleted_at IS NULL")` works fine for me.

Comment: Updated to show full Query that actually works and then the one line that is changed that breaks. I also included the full error output.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the name of the column. You just have to qualify it with the table's name or alias where it belongs, something like `AND t._deleted_at IS NULL`.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was able to call it by the alias. Several of the tables involved all had the same column name

Comment: Please consider posting a brief answer to benefit future readers.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by referencing the alias for _deleted_at. The line

```
 WHERE GroupId = 22492\
```

was changed to

```
 WHERE GroupId = 22492 AND registry._deleted_at IS NULL\
```

More than one table in the query had the same column "_deleted_at"